# How to Check for Updates in RAD Studio

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

[This page](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Check_for_Updates) mentions an option to check for updates, *without mentioning where it's located* (great job). So where is it ?

Using the integrated search function does not yield results.

Comment: The last time I saw this start menu entry was Delphi 10 Seattle.

Comment: These days available patches are announced on the Welcome Page within RAD Studio itself.

Comment: In addition to the Welcome page that @AndreasRejbrand mentioned, any updates available will also be displayed in GetIt.

Comment: Where does it show that on the Welcome page ? I know I am on 10.3 (no idea where I can find the next digit ?), but that 10.4 is out.